# How to relate these two definition of sheaf of regular function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Gortz and Wedhorn's Algebraic geometry book the sheaf of regular function on $U$ is defined as :

Definition 1.39. Let $X$ be an irreducible affine algebraic set and let $\emptyset \neq U \subseteq X$ be open. We denote by $\mathfrak{m}_x$ the maximal ideal of $\Gamma(X)$ corresponding to $x \in X$ and by $\Gamma(X)_{\mathfrak{m}_x}$ the localization of the affine coordinate ring with respect to $\mathfrak{m}_x$. We define
$$
\mathscr{O}_X(U)=\bigcap_{x \in U} \Gamma(X)_{\mathfrak{m}_x} \subset K(X) .
$$
We let $\mathscr{O}_X(\emptyset)$ be a singleton.

This definition is not the same as what I typically learned, which is pointwise defined to be the regular if exist some $f/h$ represent the map and $h\ne 0$ aroud that point.

---

I want to see that these two definition are the same , But I don't know how to write it down precisely.

A side question, the element in $\bigcap_{x \in U} \Gamma(X)_{\mathfrak{m}_x} $ may not have single representative correct?(I mean there may not have a $f/g$ with $g\notin \mathfrak{m}_x$ for all $x$)

Comment: For the side question Gortz and Wedhorn already gives a remark in 1.41 the answer is yes there may not have a single representative element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in U$. Any element $\in
\mathscr{O}_X(U)=\bigcap_{x \in U} \Gamma(X)_{\mathfrak{m}_x} \subset K(X)$ has a representation $f/g$ with $g(x)\neq 0$($\iff g\in \Gamma (X)\setminus \mathfrak{m}_x$). We can define a map $U \to K$ using the representation. This establishes Görtz-Wedhorn $\Longrightarrow$ your definition.

Conversely, suppose we have a map which can be represented as $f/g\in K(X)$ locally. If we have two such representations $f_1/g_1, f_2/g_2$, the intersection of their domains of definition $D(g_1)\cap D(g_2)=D(g_1g_2)\neq \varnothing$ since $X$ is irreducible. Then Lemma 1.38 ensures $f_1/g_1=f_2/g_2$ as elements of $K(X)$. This shows the map $$\{\text{locally representable map on }U\}\to
\mathscr{O}_X(U)=\bigcap_{x \in U} \Gamma(X)_{\mathfrak{m}_x} \subset K(X)$$
is well defined, so that we have your definition $\Longrightarrow $Görtz-Wedhorn.

Comment: Thank you @Acrobatic , I see now the alternative definition on the post is just the image of $\text{Gortz-Wedhorn}$ definition via the map $\mathscr{O}_X(U)\to \text{Map}(U,k)$ correct?

Comment: Do you have example of only locally representable map ? I feel a bit abstract, it will be much better to understand it with example @Acrobatic

Comment: @ yili Yes it is. I noticed now that the authors have constructed the first map after definition 1.39.

Comment: Got it, thank you do you have examples?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know any such examples other than example 5.36. The authors use an argument on dimension. What is happening there is, intuitively, intersection of the zeros of two polynomials must be a surface in $\mathbb{A}^4$, as in $\mathbb{R}^3$ intersection of two plane is a line.

Comment: Thank you Acrobatic, I will look at this example when reading that chapter